# Why does Poetry report a connection error over VPN when pip works

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry

Platform: Windows 10, pip 21.1, poetry 1.1.8, poetry-core 1.0.4

On my laptop I'm seeing the following behavior,

When on open wifi:  Pip and Poetry both install packages no problem

When on work VPN: Pip works fine but Poetry reports the following:

```
Using version ^6.2.5 for pytest

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

  ConnectionError

  ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

  at c:\users\[redacted]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py:498 in send
      494¦                     low_conn.close()
      495¦                     raise
      496¦
      497¦         except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
    ? 498¦             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
      499¦
      500¦         except MaxRetryError as e:
      501¦             if isinstance(e.reason, ConnectTimeoutError):
      502¦                 # TODO: Remove this in 3.0.0: see #2811
```

If both pip and poetry were failing it would seem obvious that it's a VPN or other networking issue, but since pip works, I'm puzzled about what might be going on here.

n.b., I haven't tried this with the latest versions of poetry due to an outstanding bug

Comment: Possibly related to https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/732